# Fill DataGrid in WPF C# with Directory.GetDirectories(Path)

Tags: c#, wpf, directory, datagrid

I am using code like this:

```cs
var s = Directory.GetDirectories(NAS PATH)
```

Then I fill `DataGrid` with it like this:

```cs
RandomDataGridName.ItemsSource = s
```

The problem I get is that when using `Listbox` it works fine but once I use `DataGrid` I get only the length filled in `DataGrid`.

So I have done the following:

```xml
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding }" Header="Name"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

The above code works but I only get the name column containing the entire path of the folders in NAS.

I would like to get standard date and the rest of the information that Windows keeps about its folders so users can sort directories by date.

To sum up my question:

1. Can `DataGrid` benefit from `Directory.GetDirectories()`?
2. Can I trim the `DataGrid` displayed path so the user does not see the full path of the directories; rather just the last names of folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get more info using [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-5.0) object:

```
var folder = new DirectoryInfo(NAS_PATH);
DirectoryInfo[] subdir = folder.GetDirectories();
RandomDataGridName.ItemsSource = subdir;
```

note `DirectoryInfo[]` result (instead of `string[]` from Directory.GetDirectories which simply gives paths)

then configure DataGrid to show relevant properties

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding CreationTime}" Header="CreationTime"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Works like a glove, thanks a bunch.